# Blazor StateHasChanged not working in custom eventhandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an event handler which firing a model to another component in blazor.

```
public class NotifyStateService
{
    public event EventHandler<CascadingItemEventArgs>? UpdateSubDropdownEvent;

    public void NotifySubDropdown(object sender, CascadingItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.UpdateSubDropdownEvent != null)
            UpdateSubDropdownEvent(sender, e);
    }
}

public class CascadingItemEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private CascadingDropdownModel _model;
    public CascadingItemEventArgs(CascadingDropdownModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public CascadingDropdownModel CascadingModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _model;
        }
        set
        {
            _model = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When i invoke my notify it works proper and i can get the value from it. Then i can do my work. But it is not changing the UI by StateHasChanged() method.

```
private async void UpdateSubDropdown(object sender,CascadingItemEventArgs  e)
    {
        if (BaseId.HasValue && HtmlName == e.CascadingModel.EffectiveId)
        {
            Regions = Task.Run(() => _apiClient.GetServiceResultAsync<UserRegionModel[]>($"UserRegion/GetByBaseId/{e.CascadingModel.Value}", Token)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
        }
    }
```

In the front-end of the component i need to show new regions but i couldn't. I made a lot of tests but need to find a proper way for it.

Note: Regions are filling correctly.

Comment: "Regions are filling correctly." means this part of the code works correctly. But we can't see how it fits in with your UI.

Comment: @HH yes indeed. I couldn't see the regions in the UI

Comment: What I meant is that this questin lacks the right details and is not likely to get an answer here. Consider setting up a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler should look like this:

```cs
private async void UpdateSubDropdown(object sender,CascadingItemEventArgs  e)
    {
        if (BaseId.HasValue && HtmlName == e.CascadingModel.EffectiveId)
        {
            Regions = await _apiClient.GetServiceResultAsync<UserRegionModel[]>($"UserRegion/GetByBaseId/{e.CascadingModel.Value}", Token));
            this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }
```

Unless you're an async expert, keep it simple.

If this doesn't work can you show us a minimal reproducible example?  How are you displaying `Regions`?

Comment: The `await` is an improvement but not critical, "Regions are filling correctly".

Comment: And the Task.Run() didn't hurt, this is for Blazor Server.

Comment: Agree on all points, but the only reason we believe this is Server is because the OP chose the `blazor-server-side` tag.  `GetServiceResultAsync<UserRegionModel[]>($"UserRegion/GetByBaseId/{e.CascadingModel.Value}"` looks like it's making an API call, so I'm not so sure.   And `.GetResult()` can kill your app!  I'm only fishing at this point, as the OP hasn't given us a lot to go on.